# What is nm telling me regarding the vtable in this program compiled with gcc on Linux?

Tags: c++, inheritance, gcc, vtable, nm

I changed a Base class to be abstract (i.e. I made one of its methods pure virtual) and recompiled it. When I went to link it with the derived class, the linker complained about the vtable. I investigated things with nm, but I am not sure exactly what nm was telling me. I fixed things simply by removing the *.o files and recompiling the Derived class, but I would like to understand what exactly was going on with the vtable here.

My original code was this:

Base.h

```
class Base {
    public:
       virtual void doSomething();
};
```

Base.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Base.h>
void Base::doSomething() {
    std::cout << "Base::doSomething()" << "\n";
}
```

Derived.h

```
#include <Base.h>
class Derived : public Base {
    public:
        Derived();
        void doSomething() override;
};
```

Derived.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Derived.h>
Derived::Derived() {
    std::cout << "Derived::Derived() constructor" << "\n";
}
void Derived::doSomething() {
    std::cout << "Derived::doSomething()" << "\n";
}
```

The Makefile contained the following:

```
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -I ./

default: build
clean:
    rm -f proggy
    rm -f *.o

proggy: proggy.o Base.o Derived.o 
    g++ -o proggy proggy.o Base.o Derived.o

Base.o: Base.cpp Base.h
Derived.o: Derived.cpp Derived.h
```

I then ran make and all was well. For the record, I ran nm at this point too, as follows:

```
$ nm -C Derived.o | grep Base
00000000 W Base::Base()
00000000 W Base::Base()
00000000 n Base::Base()
         U typeinfo for Base
         U vtable for Base
```

where I see that **typeinfo for Base** is undefined, but it all seems happy enough with this.

Also, in Base.o there is this at this stage:

```
nm -C Base.o | grep Base
000000d4 t _GLOBAL__sub_I__ZN4Base11doSomethingEv
00000000 T Base::doSomething()
00000044 R typeinfo for Base
0000004c R typeinfo name for Base
00000038 R vtable for Base
```

I then altered Base.h and Base.cpp as follows to make the class abstract:

Base.h

```
class Base {
    public:
       virtual void doSomething() = 0; // pure virtual
};
```

Base.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Base.h>
// void Base::doSomething() {
//     std::cout << "Base::doSomething()" << "\n";
// }
```

And then when I ran make I got this error:

```
$ make proggy
g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -I ./   -c -o Base.o Base.cpp
g++ -o proggy proggy.o Base.o Derived.o
Derived.o:(.rodata+0x5c): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Base'
Derived.o: In function `Base::Base()':
Derived.cpp:(.text._ZN4BaseC2Ev[_ZN4BaseC5Ev]+0x48): undefined reference to `vtable for Base'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:17: recipe for target 'proggy' failed
make: *** [proggy] Error 1
```

where c++filt tells me the following:

```
$ c++filt _ZN4BaseC2Ev
Base::Base()
```

So I then ran nm as follows and it told me this:

```
$ nm -C Derived.o | grep Base
00000000 W Base::Base()
00000000 W Base::Base()
00000000 n Base::Base()
         U typeinfo for Base
         U vtable for Base
```

I can see that **typeinfo for Base** is undefined, but then it was at the very start too, so I thought this was not a concern, but it is. Note also that there was no mention of Base in Base.o now.

```
$ nm -C Base.o | grep Base
```

i.e. nothing was found by this nm and grep command.

Finally, I removed all the *.o files and ran make again and all was well again. I then ran nm to see what nm reports and it reports the following:

```
$ nm -C Derived.o | grep Base
00000000 W Base::Base()
00000000 W Base::Base()
00000000 n Base::Base()
00000000 V typeinfo for Base
00000000 V typeinfo name for Base
00000000 V vtable for Base
```

What does this all mean?

My questions are:

1. What is nm telling me here and what went wrong earlier with the
   vtable?
2. What did derived need that it didn't have?
3. Why did recompiling the derived class fix things and what did this
   fix regarding the vtable?

Comment: Seems more like a Makefile/dependency problem? Not sure but maybe you removed base.cpp but base.o was still there and was linked against, but base.o at that point was for a rather different class. One without a proper vtable. Then after recompiling all is fine because Derived now sees Base is pure virtual, so the compiler does everything needed. Like creating vtable.

Comment: Your makefile is broken. When you change Base.h, Derived.cpp should be recompiled. It isn't. Fix the makefile.

Comment: Base.cpp was not removed. All that changed was Base.cpp, Base.h and Base.o. Then the linker complained. Yes, the makefile dependency is broken, but what I am interested in is the vtable. When you say the compiler creates the vtable on recompilation, how does that differ to the vtable for the original code that had no pure virtual methods?  And where does the vtable live in each case and how does the linker satisfy itself that it has everything it needs? I mean, what is the linker looking for and doing regarding the vtable?

Comment: As for the three questions in the end, the answers would be too technical, compiler-specific, and not that interesting. There are certain ways in which abstract classes' layout differs from that of otherwise identical concrete classes. What are those exactly is not at all important. What is important is that there is a difference where none is allowed by the standard.

Comment: "When you say the compiler creates the vtable on recompilation, how does that differ to the vtable for the original code that had no pure virtual methods? And where does the vtable live in each case and how does the linker satisfy itself that it has everything it needs?" Those are  implementation details which are mostly of interest to compiler writers, not to compiler users. They differ between compilers, compiler versions, architectures and what not.

Comment: Thanks n.m.  In other words, just make sure I always build all dependencies and then linking should all be fine. When you say a difference, you mean a difference in what exactly? The layout of the abstract and non-abstract classes in the Base.o file? Or Derived.o file? Or both?

Comment: The layout must be the same between all .o files. It's the fact that it isn't the same which causes breakage. The actual difference is between a class where all virtual functions are inline and a class where some virtual functions are out-of-line. In one case copies of the vtable is placed in all .o files that use it, in the other case there's one copy in a single .o file.

Comment: "_Note also that there was no mention of Base in Base.o now._" Of course: all functions are inline. A source file with only inline function need not generate any symbol.

Comment: @n.m. "_Your makefile is broken_"  You shouldn't ever write C/C++ dependencies in a makefile. If you cannot manage to have a tool to produce the dependencies from the source code, drop `make`. This program is garbage anyway.

Comment: should the definition be `void Derived::doSomething() override {` and not `void Derived::doSomething() {` in Derived.cpp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vtable stores the addresses of the implemented virtual methods. If all methods of a class are pure-virtual and none are implemented, then no vtable needs to be generated yet*, because there is no way to instantiate such a class by itself (in debug mode the vtable may still be generated, pointing everything to a trap function).

When you compile `Derived.cpp` with `Base.h` having a non-pure virtual function, it references the vtable of `Base`.

When you subsequently change `Base.h` to have only pure virtual functions and rebuild `Base.o`, the vtable from `Base.o` disappears. At this point you need to rebuild `Derived.o`, otherwise it will keep on referencing the non-existing vtable.

When you rebuild `Derived.o`, the compiler sees that `Base` is a pure-virtual class and generates a vtable for it in `Derived.o` itself because it knows there isn't one in `Base.o`.

Another potential issue arises after reordering virtual functions in the base class. Then derived classes, if not rebuilt, can end up invoking the wrong functions in their parent class.

That's why it is important to get the dependency chain right to make sure dependent object files are rebuilt when necessary.

```
Derived.o: Derived.cpp Derived.h Base.h
```

---

* the gory details are compiler-dependent but the way GCC does it is: since it's impossible to instantiate a pure-virtual class, the vtable generation is actually *postponed* until there is at least one implementation, because only then it is actually possible to have an instance of the class. So the vtable is generated with every derived implementation and exported as a "weak" object (type `V`) to allow for potential duplicates to be merged at link time.

Comment: The relevant line that's missing from the Makefile to prevent the issue is `Derived.o: Base.h`.

Comment: So when the linker sees "U typeinfo for Base" in Derived.o, it expects to find the definition elsewhere, such as in Base.o where originally there existed "00000044 R typeinfo for Base". Q1. Is that correct?  And then later on when I had the pure virtual method in Base and everything was recompiled and happy again, things were happy because Derived.o contained "00000000 V typeinfo for Base" which I assume satisfied it and meant it was not referencing definitions that are elsewhere. Q2. Is that correct too? (And likewise for the vtable.)

Comment: Yes, the type U (undefined) means that this symbol is referenced or used in this object code/executable, but it’s value wasn’t defined here.

Comment: "_then no vtable needs to be generated_" the answer is wrong

Answer (score 6):

From the log

```
$ make proggy
g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -I ./   -c -o Base.o Base.cpp
g++ -o proggy proggy.o Base.o Derived.o
```

It means your makefile does not re-build `Derived.o`, and only re-build `Base.o`.
This of course causes the issue.

You need to fix the `Makefile` to add proper dependency for `Derive.cpp` to `Base.h`.

Comment: Thanks. Why does Derived.o need to be rebuilt?  What is wrong with it?  I guess something in it regarding the vtable is now out of date and incorrect, but what exactly?  And how does the vtable change when Derived.cpp is recompiled?  And where is this vtable?  In Base.o or in Derived.o or both?

Comment: Because it includes `Base.h`, when `Base.h` is changed, all the cpp files that include it shall be re-built.

Comment: I think you meant `Derived.o: Base.h`, not `Derived.cpp: Base.h`.

Comment: And the relevant language-lawyer explanation is that because the two translation units were compiled with different definitions of `Base`, we get Undefined Behaviour.